# Symfony error - object not found

Tags: php, symfony

I am sorry for asking such a question and I know there have been questions like this before, but my case is rather...stupid. What I have is a project management system and I want to display all projects which works fine and is auto generated by Symfony. In the same controller which is ProjectController I made another action. I wanted to list all archived projects which have been completely done. For a start I simply copy pasted the code and the annotations and changed the routes and the name of the function. Here is my `indexAction` function

```
/**
     * Lists all project entities.
     *
     * @Route("/", name="project_index")
     * @Method("GET")
     */
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $projects = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Project')->findAll();
        return $this->render('project/index.html.twig', array(
            'projects' => $projects,
        ));
    }
```

It is as simple as it can get. Now here is my `archiveAction` function which is the same

```
/**
     * Lists all project entities.
     *
     * @Route("/archive", name="project_archive")
     * @Method("GET")
     */
    public function archiveAction()
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $projects = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Project')->findAll();
        return $this->render('project/index.html.twig', array(
            'projects' => $projects,
        ));
    }
```

So far I am not even filtering the projects, but doing the exact same thing as I do in the `indexAction` function and bear in mind both functions are in the same controller. Here is the error I receive when trying to show all archived projects -

> AppBundle\Entity\Project object not found.

The index action works just fine and displays all projects, but if I change the route and change the name of the function and keep everything the same and they are in the same Controller - in one case it can find AppBUndle\Entity\Zadanie, but in the other case - it can't.

Comment: I can't view  Zadanie inside your code, where is called? Where is its code?

Comment: It is "Project" I changed it in bulgarian and forgot to redo it. It is "AppBundle:Entity:Project"

Comment: Have you tried after clearing the cache of symfony?

Comment: I have cleaned the cashe with 2 types of commands. The first - "php bin/console cache:clear" and the second "php bin/console cache:clear --env=prod --no-warmup". And I have done it several times, but the error is still active.

Comment: tr to run this command rm -Rf var/cache/* and the try it again.

Comment: It doesn't recognize it as a valid command. I am literally typing "php bin/console rm -Rf var/cache/* " this is what you meant right?

Comment: No no! just write it with out php bin/console

Comment: http://prntscr.com/fit47k this is the result. I am doing it in the main directory of my app in the terminal provided by PHPStorm. I have no idea what rm is supposed to mean.

Comment: It's supposed to remove all files inside the directory recursively... in unix systems. Try to find your equivalent command for windows.

Comment: Can't I just press the delete button on those directories??Would it cause any errors?

Comment: I deleted the dev directory in var/cache and it still shows this error. I can't understand how is it possible since it is the same code.

Comment: If you have the solution for your problem please, put it as an answer and delete it from the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**SOLVED** I managed to solve the problem by putting the archive function on top. By on top I mean in first position before any other function. Before doing so I tried switching the routes. I took the route from indexAction and put it in the annotations from the archiveAction and the opposite. Both functions worked just fine. Then I returned them as they were and archive still didn't work. Then I simply put archive in first place before index and it worked as a charm. I have no idea what just happened and why but...didn't matter...it works. ( seriously though -  if anybody knows why that is I would appreciate it)

EDIT: So 2 years and 4 months later I think I got the crank of it, the routes are cached so what I did was just clear the cache and it worked, but at the time I didnt pay attention to this detail

Comment: Same here. "object not found" error and putting my new action on top of the controller class make it work. No idea why...

Answer (score 0):

I found the same problem and I managed to find the cause of the problem.
routing problem, for example:

```
@Route ("/ {id}", name = "project_archive_show")
function2

@Route ("/ archive", name = "project_archive")
function1
```

urls must have personalized specifications:
for example :

```
@Route ("/ show / {id}", name = "project_archive_show")
function2
or says that id is an integer
```